# Trouble when Highcharts display many columns

Tags: javascript, graphics, highcharts

I'm trying to display 100 (or more) columns using highchart but getting so thin columns. The columns are so near.

I want something like that:

http://lygodactylus-williamsi.galaxyfighter.de/haltung/klima.php

Comment: What have you tried? How thick do you want them? How far apart do you want the individual columns from the next column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you debug the code you provided and see theire chart options, you'll see that don't provide any option to customize the chart. The only think is that theire chart doen't have too many columns, that's why it's not thin.

You can see the options by doing the following.

- Create a breakpoint on temp_morogoro.php at line 176.
- Refresh the page.
- When it stops on the break point, run the following script.
            `console.log(JSON.stringify(options))`
- Then you can see on your console theire chart options.

Or you can use `dataGrouping` to customize how many columns you want to display.
Take a look the following demos.

[without dataGrouping](http://jsfiddle.net/B7rGw/)
[with dataGrouping](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/column/)